# Не закрывается база данных Access, после выполнения метода

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, access, com

После того, как выполняются необходимые действия над БД, открывается пустое окно с Access'ом.
Если нажать на Закрыть по Access, то это окно снова откроется.
Только после закрытия программы Access закрывается.
В чем может быть проблема?
Вроде бы все необходимые действия, я проделываю после завершения работы:

```
static bool PatchningDB(List<Unit> patch, string pathToDB)
    {
        Application app = new Application { Visible = false };
        app.OpenCurrentDatabase(pathToDB);
        Database currentDB = app.CurrentDb();
        try
        {
            if (patch.Any(x => x.Type == "SQL"))
            {
                ProcessingQueries(patch.Where(x => x.Type == "SQL").ToList(), currentDB);
            }
            if (patch.Any(x => x.Type == "VBA"))
            {
                ProcessingQueries(patch.Where(x => x.Type == "VBA").ToList(), currentDB);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            currentDB.Close();//Неужели 
            app.CloseCurrentDatabase();//этого
            app.Quit();//мало?
        }
        return true;
    }

   static bool ProcessingQueries(List<Unit> patch, Database db)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> queryDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (QueryDef query in db.QueryDefs)
        {
            queryDict.Add(query.Name, query.Name);
        }
        foreach (var unit in patch)
        {
            if (IsQueryDeleted(queryDict, unit))
            {
                db.DeleteQueryDef(unit.Name);
            }
            if (unit.Action == "ADD")
            {
                db.CreateQueryDef(unit.Name, unit.Command);
                continue;
            }
            if (IsQueryExecuted(queryDict, unit))
            {
                db.Execute(unit.Name);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Вполне вероятно, что в методе ProcessingQueries иницируются какие-то объекты Access, после чего корректно их никто не завершает.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос реализацией метода ProcessingQueries.

Comment: Нет ли в базе Access обработчика события?

Comment: Нет. Использую базу, которая создается по дефолту. app.Quit(); Вот после строчки у меня на экране начинает висеть пустой Access без объектов...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо освобождать все используемые COM-объекты с помощью `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`.

Т.е. вам нужно добавить еще такие строчки:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentDB);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
```